# Mysql update if field value isnt 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the termek_keszlet_db field, if the value of the field isnt 0.
How can i write an if condition in the sql below?

```
$keszlet_csokkent_sql = "UPDATE termek SET termek_keszlet_db = termek_keszlet_db-$db WHERE termek_id = $id";
```

This is a stock data in a webshop, and i want to update the stock of products, if there is a new order.

Comment: You could use the IF() function to supply the value on the right side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you really want this:

```
UPDATE termek
    SET termek_keszlet_db = GREATEST(termek_keszlet_db - $db, 0)
    WHERE termek_id = $id;
```

This will ensure that `termek_keszlet_db` is never set to a negative value.

Note that `$db` and `$id` should be passed in as query parameters.  You should not munge the query string with parameter values (when you can avoid doing so).

Comment: Yes! I the termek_keszlet_db value is 10, but i order 12, after order, the termek_keszlet_db will be -2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `AND` condition `termek_keszlet_db != 0`:

```
$keszlet_csokkent_sql = "UPDATE termek SET termek_keszlet_db = termek_keszlet_db-$db WHERE termek_id = $id AND termek_keszlet_db != 0";
```

Comment: So i dont need IF?

Comment: you needed to check if the field is 0 or not, you don;t need `IF` for that.